# How to draw an image in c# with path stored in a variable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

```
private string path;

public string Path
{
    get { return path; }
    set { path = value; }
}

public override void Draw(Graphics.IGraphicsSurface g)
{
    //some code here
}
```

I need to get the image stored at the location `path` on my file system and draw it on the surface, `g`, using the `DrawImage()` function.

EDIT:
The first parameter being passed to `DrawImage()` must be a string 
`public void DrawImage(string image, float x, float y)` 
OR file Stream 
`public void DrawImage(Stream imageStream, float x, float y)`

```
public void DrawImage(string image, float x, float y)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(image))
        {
            Stream stream = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open);
            DrawImage(stream, new Graphics.Point(x, y));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What platform are you targetting? Winforms, WPF, ASP...???

Comment: @TaW winforms ... its basically a pptx viewer .. i have parsed the images but getting problem in drawing

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can use [`Image.FromFile(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var image = Image.FromFile(path);

g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

This will draw the image at the point (0, 0).

---

However, OP is required to use a different `DrawImage` method which takes in a string. For this, we can simply say:

```
g.DrawImage(path, 0, 0);
```

Comment: The first parameter being passed to DrawImage(,) must be a string - 
`public void DrawImage(string image, float x, float y)` 
OR 
a file Stream
`public void DrawImage(Stream imageStream, float x, float y)`
Sorry I failed to mention this in the beginning. It is overridden function

Comment: @DhanushD I am referencing [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1(v=vs.110).aspx). Did you define your own `DrawImage` method?

Comment: No I am not supposed to use the method you showed . A new DrawImage  has been overridden and defined. I need to use that. The overridden functions are quoted above

Comment: @DhanushD Do you have the source of the method that takes a `string`? Can you post it?

Comment: `public void DrawImage(string image, float x, float y)
{
  try
    {
      if (File.Exists(image))
        {
           Stream stream = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open);
           DrawImage(stream, new Graphics.Point(x, y));
        }
     }
   catch(Exception)
    {
    }
}`

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (dlg.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
        }
    }
```